# interprocess communication between multiple apps (app chain) and multiple chains via dbus

Tags: linux, ipc, dbus

I'm writing a SW for a real HW which I don't have currently. The SW consists of multiple apps which should communicate between each other over some bus, e.g. I2C or any other bus. I was thinking to use dbus to simulate the HW bus interconnect. The API would be the same for all platforms, but the underlying layer would be either an I2C driver or the dbus simulation. For better imagination the structure may look following way:

[image]

I've already experimented with dbus a bit and this seems to be feasible - I guess there would be a server which would interconnect all the apps between each other and APP1 would communicate over the server with APP2 etc. Is my understanding correct?

However, what came on my mind was, that during testing, I'm executing multiple instances to execute tests in parallel and that's what I'm not sure about, whether this would be possible over dbus. If there are multiple instances of APP1-1/2-1/3-1 (APPx_y - x APP number, y - instance number), how would one say, that APP1 instance 1 should communicate with APP2 instance 2 etc.? Is it even possible using dbus? Is there some inherent mechanism in dbus for such a case or I would need to implement this additionally into the dbus server and the dbus app clients using some session number, which would be used during app startup or so?

Answer (score 0):

> If there are multiple instances of APP1-1/2-1/3-1 (APPx_y - x APP number, y - instance number), how would one say, that APP1 instance 1 should communicate with APP2 instance 2 etc.? Is it even possible using dbus?

Add a distinguisher to the bus names that your apps claim (if they do). For example, if your app was going to claim `com.renegade.App1`, make it `com.renegade.App1.Session3` or something like that – and of course make the other apps look for this style of name.

(When GUI multi-instance apps claim a "well-known name", they *usually* add their process ID as an additional component – e.g. `org.mozilla.Firefox` could become `org.mozilla.Firefox.4567`. (In reality Firefox actually adds the profile name, like `org.mozilla.Firefox.default`.))

Only "server" apps need to do this, if the app wants to be known by name. Pure clients that only make bus calls but not receive them don't need to claim a name at all; they'll still work using the automatic "unique name" that they get upon connection.